# Change proxy_pass if condition is met?

Tags: nginx

I want to use an upstream most of the time, but others I want to allow specifying the target server based on an X-Target-Server request header.

I have a server that looks for a request variable and maps it as part of my nginx.conf. I then have a virtual server conf that does the following:

```
proxy_pass https://backend_dev_test;
if ($is_target_specified) {
  proxy_pass https://$http_x_target_server;
}
```

What happens when the proxy_pass directive is specified? Does it run immediately? Would this cause it to run twice? Or would it only target the second if the condition is met?

It seems to work in some location blocks but not others and I don't understand why. Is there a better way to approach this? Full locations below

Seems to work

```
location ~* /v3/(test|other)/ {
  proxy_cache_bypass "1";
  proxy_no_cache "1";
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
  rewrite ^/v3/(.*)$ /$1 break;
  proxy_pass https://backend_dev_test;
  if ($is_target_specified) {
    proxy_pass https://$http_x_target_server;
  }
}
```

Seems to not work

```
location ~* /v3 {
  proxy_cache_bypass "1";
  proxy_no_cache "1";
  resolver 8.8.8.8;
  proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
  proxy_pass https://backend_dev;
  if ($is_target_specified) {
    proxy_pass https://$http_x_target_server;
  }
}
```